# Sort a splitted array string with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I've tried the following:

```
var tags in c.Tags.Split(',').OrderBy( x > x )
```

where c.Tags is a string of tags seperated by ',', is there a way I can sort it with OrderBy?

Comment: You already have the answer (just change `in` to `=` and `>` to `=>`)

Comment: Can also be done without Linq, with `var tags = c.Tags.Split(','); Array.Sort(tags);`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you're using this in a `foreach`:

```
foreach(var tags in c.Tags.Split(',').OrderBy( x => x ))
{
   //...
}
```

or as an assignment:

```
var tags = c.Tags.Split(',').OrderBy( x => x );
```